# Is there any limit with number of images I can save with UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I’ve implemented UIActivityViewController in my application. It requires me to share multiple images. The number can vary from 1 to 150.

Suppose I have 11 images to share. When the Share Sheet is shown and I click on Save 11 Images. Only 5 images are saved to Photos. But that is not the case with Copy operation, Mail, Messages, Notes and any other capable applications. In all other applications I was able to save all 11 images.

This left me wondering there is indeed a limit on number of images that can be saved to Photos app.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: @Mr.Bean No. are you facing the same issue?

Comment: Yes !! I am still facing the issue